# Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways to go n miles by fast walking at 2 miles per hour or

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

A) Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways to go n miles by fast walking at 2 miles per hour or jogging at 4 miles per hour or running at 8 miles per hour; at the end of each hour a choice is made of how to go the next hour.
B) How many ways are there to go 12 miles?

I tried to start the problem with 
$a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-4}+a_{n-8}$ But I don't know if I am on the correct track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, your recurrence relation is correct but you have to be little cautious here. Since you can go even number of miles at each hour, what should be the answer if i ask you this question: "How many ways are there to go n miles? where n is odd,e.g-n=3". Certainly you can go 2 miles, 4 miles but there is no way you can make exactly 3 miles.You can say, that there is no way to go exactly 3 miles, in that case you an define your recurrence in this way:

$a_0 = 1.$ 

$a_i =0$, when i is odd or negative integer.

$a_i = a_{i-2} + a_{i-4} + a_{i-8}$ otherwise.

Comment: So if I were looking for the number of ways to go 12 miles, would me answer be 17 ways?

Comment: $a_0$ = 1.
$a_2$ = 1 + 0 + 0 = 1.
$a_4$ = $a_2$ + $a_0$ + 0 = 2.
$a_6$ = $a_4$ + $a_2$ + 0 = 3.
$a_8$ = $a_6$ + $a_4$ + $a_0$ = 6.
$a_{10}$ = $a_8$ + $a_6$ + $a_2$ = 10.
$a_{12}$ = $a_{10}$ + $a_8$ + $a_4$ = 10 + 6 + 2 = 18.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation (seems to me) is correct, but you have to add initial conditions (you can not start recurrence/program from empty air); using notation a(n) instead of your an (easier in HTML) add 
a(1) = 0.5;
a(2) = a(3) = 1;
a(4) = 2; // walk or jog
etc - you certainly can finish yourself

Comment: Could you clsrify how you got a(1)=0.5. The way I was looking at a(1) is that there are 3 ways to travel the 1 mile. Similarly: a(2)=3 and a(3)=3[ways to travel 2 miles]+1[way to travel @4mph]+1[way to travel @8mph]

Comment: number of ways cannot be a fraction.